# Solr issues with MAMP MySQL Data Import

Tags: mysql, solr, mamp, mamp-pro

I am having a problem trying to get Solr to connect with MySQL running on my local MAMP installation to do a data import.

I have setup my data-config.xml file like so:

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/***"
            user="root"
            password="root"
            batchSize="-1"
            readOnly="true" /> 
  <document>
    <entity name="id" query="SELECT show_id AS 'id', name, description FROM ***;">

        <field column="show_id" name="id" />
        <field column="name" name="name" />
        <field column="description" name="description" />

    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I have also added the following to my solrconfig.xml file:

```
  <lib dir="../../../libexec/contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../libexec/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />

    <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
              <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
          </lst>
    </requestHandler> 
    <lib dir="../../../libexec/dist/mysql/" regex="mysql-connector-java-\d.*\.jar" />
```

I run the following to do a data import:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/dataimport?command=full-import&debug=true&verbose=true
```

But I get the following:

```
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT show_id AS 'id', name, description FROM tbl_hbo_shows; Processing Document # 1 at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:71) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:283) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:240) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:44) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DebugLogger$2.getData(DebugLogger.java:188) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:243) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:476) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:415) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:330) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:232) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:416) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:480) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.handleRequestBody(DataImportHandler.java:189) at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1967) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:777) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:418) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137) at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004) at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640) at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor21.newInstance(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:338) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2232) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790) at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44) at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor18.newInstance(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395) at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:153) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:133) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:402) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:44) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:270) ... 43 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:213) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:297) ... 59 more
```

I am running Solr 4.10.2 with MAMP Pro to handle the MySQL database connection. I have looked at various similar issues online but changes to my connection url etc. do not seem to resolve the issue.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by finally finding out I was getting the error:

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Using point 1 of the answer at:

https://serverfault.com/questions/89955/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-through-jdbc-connector-through-tomcat-or-externally

...solved the problem!